# FrameLayout or Nested Fragments?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, code-organization, android-framelayout

### My problem

I am in a dilemma. I have a fragment which has 3 different modes. Well, it is a history fragment.
The modes are:

- Overview (displays `GridView`);
- Cell (displays `GridView's` cell);
- Empty (displays `ImageView` and `TextView`);

### My question

So I can't understand how to organise this. Should I **use three fragments (use nested fragments) for each mode** as a child into parent fragment? Or just **use one fragment with `FrameLayout`** and switch between different layouts? What is the best solution? Share your ideas!

*I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for multiple fragments approach. It does not only help you to build reusable UI elements but also to easily supports multiple screen sizes (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design).

However, I think you only need two fragments: one fragment for the "Overview" mode and another fragment for the "Cell" mode.

You don't need a fragment for the empty mode. You should construct a view with `ImageView` and `TextView` and set it to the `GridView` of the "Overview" fragment as an `emptyView` (using `GridView.setEmptyView(View)`).

Comment: Good opinion! But my problem is a little bit deeper: this fragment is attached into ViewPager, so I can't just replace it via Transaction. Cause of this I should make some kind of "parent" fragment for history and then insert fragments into it. But according Google's: _Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly._ So I think nested fragment is a bad idea and FrameLayout is a good one. Isn't it?

Comment: Well, then I would replace the parent fragment that holds the view pager with cell fragment when needed, via the host Activity. So it will use multiple fragments but not really nested fragments.

Comment: I think FrameLayout maybe simple and easy to implement for now, but multiple fragments will give you more benefits in long term, in term of reusablity and maintainability.